# I can't access the group attribute of FormBuilder on my reactive form

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Property 'group' does not exist on type 'typeof FormBuilder'

here is the code

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class LoginPageForm{

  constructor(private formBuilder = FormBuilder){}

  createForm(): FormGroup{
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From:

```js
constructor(private formBuilder = FormBuilder){}
```

you are declaring the `formBuilder` and initializing it with the value of `FormBuilder` type.

```
formBuilder = typeof(FormBuilder)
```

isn't equivalent to

```
formBuilder: FormBuilder
```

which store `FormBuilder` instance.

---

Instead, specify `formBuilder` as `FormBuilder` type.

```js
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Yong Shun, it worked really good. I'm grateful